# Insert into a table from a stored procedure with multiple output sets is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I need to populate a table from a stored procedure output. I have tried below query.

```
DECLARE @Result AS TABLE (ouid int, value1 nvarchar(max), value2 nvarchar(max), value3 nvarchar(max))

insert into @Result (value1 ,value2, value3)
    exec [USP_Getofficevalues] 1, NULL, NULL
```

But I got the errors during execution:

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
>
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

I found that the error occurs because the stored procedure has multiple result sets, like this:

```
officedetails
-------------
500000

value1
-----
1000

value2
-----
500

value3
-----
800
```

How to handle the above scenario? Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible to change the Stored Procedure to return in single result set ?

Comment: no. its an already using sp . i couldn't change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the returned result sets are all single column and same type, you can declare a table variable and store the result:

```
declare @r table
(
    id int identity,
    value int
)

insert into @r(value)
exec [USP_Getofficevalues] 1, NULL,NULL
```

After that you just need to transpose `@r` into your `@result` table.

Answer (score 1):

Check your procedure USP_Getofficevalues.

I think it is using **Insert into** inside which is not allowed if you are using it as insert while calling.